# Map location of unknown point coordinates with two known coordinates and distances between them

Tags: distance, intersection, circle, mathematics, triangulation

I have a problem where I need to find the coordinates of a point which is the intersecting point of two circles. I found a similar question on stackoverflow.

I understood to some extent, but not able to understand how x3, y3 is written in equation form. Please refer the below link (in comment)and help me understand.

[Map location of unknown point with distances to two known points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112905/map-location-of-unknown-point-with-distances-to-two-known-points)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112905/map-location-of-unknown-point-with-distances-to-two-known-points

Comment: please clarify why your question is different from the one you have linked to

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am not able to figure out how X3,Y3 is written in that answer. As I can't comment this on the previous post i created a new one. It would be great if you can help me to figure this out